# Cannot update to Lollipop on rooted Moto G 2nd Gen

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, 5.0-lollipop, twrp

I have rooted my device a few days back. Today I received Lollipop update for my Moto G 2nd gen. I downloaded the updates and clicked on install updates.
When I clicked on Install updates, it powered off my phone and then opened TWRP screen with all its options. I had no idea about what to do next so I just clicked on "Reboot". It rebooted my device and again due to Lollipop installation, got powered off again.
My device got in power off and TWRP screen loop. I rebooted my device a few times and then it displayed me the message that the "update was unsuccessful"
Now, when I check for updates, it shows me that my software is up to date. I still have KitKat on my device.
Please help me to upgrade my Android version from KitKat to Lollipop. Please also suggest what to do when I install updates and my device powers off and start with TWRP screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get OTA updates while the phone is rooted.  What you need to do is un-root the phone, install the OTA update, then re-root the phone once you're done.

Also, OTA updates are best done using the stock recovery.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to do the same and post the result here.